# Finding seven harmonic cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, laplacian, computational-algebra, homogeneous-spaces

I am given an exercise of my thesis which is about "Computational Algeberaic Geometry", but I dont have enough knowldege to do it or even think about it. The exercixe is:

A **ternary cubic** form is a homogeneous degree 3 polynomials in three variables and the space of ternary cubic has dimension 10. I need to find a basis of seven harmonic cubics which ones killed by the **Laplace operator**. In this way, we can also compute the dimension of the space of harmonic homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables, for each of the seven cubics $f$, we should find the seven eigenvectors, that is the vectors $v \in  \mathbb{C}^3$, up to scalar, such that the gradient $(f_x, f_y, f_z)$ is proportional to $(x,y,z)$.

In some ways it is related to $3$-[Veronese Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronese_surface) of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Any help, hint and guidance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let your general ternary cubic be paramatrised by the $10$ coefficients of the degree 3 ternary monomials - i.e., parametrised by $\mathbb{P}^{10}$. Then consider the morphism enduced by the laplace operator - this will be some projective matrix (or taking an affine chart, some matrix) compute its kernel

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get it, I mean I don't have sufficient knowledge about Laplace operators, I may ask you to write precisely if you mind.

Comment: You don't need any knowledge about the Laplacian other than the *definition* and the observation that it is a linear operator. If this is for your thesis, you'd better start doing some serious work. If you are a doctoral student, you should be able to do an undergraduate exercise by looking up a definition and calculating.

Comment: I have just started, taking the first step! I just know basic algebra and algebraic geometry, and I am willing to work hard.

Comment: So let me explain what I got:
$$ f: \mathbb{C}[x,y,z] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$$
$$ ax^3+by^3+cz^3+dx^2y+ex^2z+fy^2x+gy^2z+hz^2x+iz^2y+kxyz \mapsto \Delta f$$ 

$$= (6ax+2dy+2ez)+(6by+2fx+2gz)+(6cz+2hx+2iy)= 2(3a+f+h)x+2(2b+d+i)y+2(3c+e+g)= Ax+By+Cz ,$$
Am I doing right?

Comment: So it is obviously a linear operator, and null space will have dimension of 7, it means every rows in transformation matrix will span a harmonic cubic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{P}_k^{9}$ parametrise the space of ternary cubics over $k$, where the $i^{th}$ coordinate gives the coefficient of the $i^{th}$ monomial in, say, lexigraphical order. The Laplacian is a linear operator which takes the space of ternary cubics to the space of homogeneous linear forms on $k$. That is, we may view $\nabla^2$ a linear map
$$\nabla^2 : \mathbb{P}_k^{9} \to \mathbb{P}_k^{2}$$
on the parameter spaces. Say given by multiplying by a matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 10}(k)$ (defined up to scalar multiplication by a unit).

The kernel of this matrix gives corresponds to the linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}_k^{9}$ parametrising ternary cubics vanishing under $\nabla^2$. Given the coefficient space it is obvious how to write down the original cubics.

If you are allowing rings it should be clear how to generalise this, as with higher degree polynomials. The above is also more or less an algorithm for computing this space too.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, so the way of my thinking was true, just need to write and practice more. Another question went through my mind was about eigenvectors, what do they indicate?

Comment: @B.K-Theory I'm sorry, eigenspaces are for endomorphisms of vector spaces $V \to V$, this clearly does not apply here

Comment: yes you are correct, my mistake.